# Link to local html file

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, localhost

Im trying to put a link to local html file called **Rules.html**,
but for some reason I cannot make it work.

Html file is in the same folder as my php file.

Note that Im running my forum on **localhost:1337**, Should that be somewhere in that line too?
Here is my piece of code:

```
   <li class="copyright">
    <a class="rules" href="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/SMF/smf_2-0-6_install/Themes   
    /Fresh_v2_RC5/Rules.html">Rules</a>
   </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the same folder as the file you are calling it from, you can just call it by name, instead of it's complete path.

```
<li class="copyright">
    <a class="rules" href="Rules.html">Rules</a></li>
```

Also, if you are calling it by it's full path name, you do not want to use `file:` to open a linked html document. You would call:

edit: (added // in front of localhost.)

```
<li class="copyright">
    <a class="rules" href="//localhost/../Rules.html">Rules</a></li>
```

And pull it up in your apache server. Using file is like opening the file in your file system, but to view html, use your web server.

Comment: I've tried that too but still no luck. It says object not found. I think it has something to do with localhost but no idea how to solve it

Comment: Object not found? Normally, if you link to a page that does not exist, when you click the link it says something along the lines of "Rules.html does not exist on this server".

Comment: You tried my firest suggestion, right? Just using the filename? Also, make sure that the file is named Rules.html and not rules.html. Capitalization matters. Also, note my edit above, try that as well.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I did try every single suggestion but still no luck

Comment: Does it still say "Object not found"? If so, are you still linking to "file:"? Can you edit your post with your new code after making the change?

Comment: With that piece of code it says "Unable to connect, Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.
        <td align= "left">
        <ul class="reset">
        <li class="copyright">
        <a class="rules" href="//localhost/../Rules.html">Rules</a></li></td>

With this piece it says Object not found. The requested URL was not found on this server.
     <td align= "left">
        <ul class="reset">
        <li class="copyright">
        <a class="rules" href="Rules.html">Rules</a></li></td>
 File is 100% in the same folder and it works just fine when I click on it

Comment: Ahhh ok, now we are getting somewhere. Sorry, I didn't know about this unable to connect error. So, this has NOTHING to do with the link now. This is the server is not up and running. You have an apache server? Was it working before today? Does it pull up the php page? Refresh and see if it still pulls up the php page.

Comment: Yes I've apache server up and running. Php page working no problem all day. Was it working before? N/A Didnt try to put that link before.

Comment: And captialization? Open the properties of the Rules.html make sure that it is exactly Rules.html and not rules.html (or rules.php for that matter)

Comment: Capitalization is spot on. Checked it hundreds of times.

Comment: Try this:  <a class="rules" href= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."Rules.html">Rules</a>

Comment: Basically, this way we can be 100% sure that it is looking for this file in the document root

Comment: Syntax error
 unexpected: identifier 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'
 after: String ''
 <div id="footer_section"><div class="frame">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td align= "left">
        <ul class="reset">
        <li class="copyright">
        <a class="rules" href= $_SERVER[''
 expected: instanceof, as, =>, }, ',', OR, XOR, &&, ?, ;, ||, &&, |, ^, &, ==, !=, ===, !==, <=, >=, <, >, <<, >>, +, -, *, /, %, '.', ], ), :

POSSIBLE Syntax Error (check preceding valid syntax error)
 unexpected: String '']."Rules.html">Rules</a>
            </li></td>
        <td>

Comment: I think I gave you enough headache for today. Thank you for being so kind

Comment: No problem at all. At work, in between trouble tickets, so I don't mind. That was my hail mary though haha. I am completely at a loss.

Comment: I'll try to tackle it some other day. Otherwise wont be able to sleep. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using relative links. So the link would be

```
href="theFile.html"
```

if it's in the same folder as the file you are trying to write the link in.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path from your `root` dir. `Root` dir is a dir where located your html file within this code. For example, if you put this code in html file, located in `htdocs` dir, so the relative link is:

```
<li class="copyright">
    <a class="rules" href="SMF/smf_2-0-6_install/Themes/Fresh_v2_RC5/Rules.html">Rules</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it's easiest in this case to simply use relative urls.

The way to do this with the code you've provided:

```
<li class="copyright">
    <a class="rules" href="Rules.html">Rules</a>
</li>
```

Make sure that this `Rules.html` file is in the same directory (dir) as the file from which you're calling it. If not, you'll need to do some directory traversing to get to it.

[Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626075/path-to-folder-outside-of-folder) with some helpful examples.